# How do I access the AZ Service Bus without a SAS Key

Tags: azure, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-security

I need help in creating access to AZ a service bus without using thr Shared Access Key in an Azure Function.
When I use the Endpoint, SharedAccessKeyName,  SharedAccessKey, QueueName and RuleName it works great!
I can create the connection string like this:

```java
string connectionString = string.Format("Endpoint={0};SharedAccessKeyName={1};SharedAccessKey={2}", Endpoint, SharedAccessKeyName, SharedAccessKey);

Manager = new Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration.ServiceBusAdministrationClient(connectionString);
```

I was told that I can use the AZ Identity to accomplish this same thing without the SAS Key.
I have not been able to figure out how to do this. In fact, I do not even know where to begin.

Comment: Instead of a connection string, you would use a Uri + TokenCredential. You use the Azure.Identity library to construct the kind of TokenCredential you want to use. In most scenarios, DefaultAzureCredential works well, but there are others if you need a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your app to run under a `managed Identity`, and then *configure* your Azure Service Bus resource to allow access for that identity.
See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-managed-service-identity) and the sample code [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-msi-servicebus-dotnet).